# Extract CSS style declarations with python

Tags: python, html, css, lxml

I am parsing a html file using lxml.html, however, i need to get the HTML classes that are used as selectors in the stylesheet i.e `['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']` with corresponing style information.

I extracted the style sections as a string tried parsing it using `cssutils.parseString` but i end up with this:

```
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'<style type="text/css">&#13;' [1:28: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [1:1: <]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [1:12: =]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected STRING. [1:13: "text/css"]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [1:24: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: <style type="text/css">&#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'<style type="text/css">&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'&#13;' [2:47: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [2:43: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: &#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'&#13;' [3:33: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [3:29: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: &#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'&#13;' [4:32: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [4:28: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: &#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'&#13;' [5:34: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [5:30: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: &#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'&#13;' [6:34: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [6:30: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: &#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'&#13;' [7:53: ;]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [7:49: &]
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: &#13
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'&#13;'
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No start { of style declaration found: u'</style>' [8:13: ]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [8:5: <]
ERROR   Selector: Unexpected CHAR. [8:6: /]
ERROR   Selector: Cannot end with combinator: </style>
ERROR   SelectorList: Invalid Selector: </style>
ERROR   CSSStyleRule: No style declaration or "}" found: u'</style>'
<cssutils.css.CSSStyleSheet object encoding='utf-8' href=None media=None title=None namespaces={} at 0x308ca90>
```

How can i solve this?

```
<style type="text/css">&#13;
    p.c6 {font-weight: bold; text-align: left}&#13;
    p.c5 {font-weight: bold}&#13;
    p.c4 {text-align: left}&#13;
    td.c3 {font-weight: bold}&#13;
    p.c2 {text-align: center}&#13;
    p.c1 {font-weight: bold; text-align: center}&#13;
</style>
```

Comment: I guess you should get rid of the surrounding `style`-tag and the printed line breaks (`&#13;`) to not have those errors.

Comment: There is even a lot more to remove to get rid of all the errors. Generated by html tidy :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you are using to get that error message?

A CSS parser (like cssutils or tinycss) expects you to give a CSS source. It appears you are giving the source of the HTML `<style>` element. You can use lxml.html to parse that HTML. Then you should extract the `text` attribute of the nodes you’re interested in, not serialize them back to HTML.

Your code should be something like this:

```
html = '<style>a.b &#123;}</style>'
lxml.html.fromstring(html)
for style_element in html.xpath('style')
    # lmxl parses HTML entities like &#123;
    assert style_element.text == 'a.b {}'
    stylesheet = cssutils.parseString(style_element.text)
```